# Google chrome allow/deny prompt for using device's webcam with google chrome apps

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, camera

At the moment google chrome provides me with security for using my device webcam, with a prompt '.. wants to use your camera' allow/deny. each time I load a page i get this option. I'm trying use the camera embedded within my google chrome app

Is there a way to make sure that once user says 'allow' the value is retrieved and user will not have to give access for that particular app.

Is there any API I could use where 'allow' or 'deny click is stored and sent back to the app so that i can do some modifications accordingly.

I cant reproduce that using my chrome browser though. I dont get any prompt for the user to allow/deny.But, client is getting this prompt and are not happy with prompt each time app tries to access camera

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about Chrome Packaged apps, you can use the "audioCapture" and "videoCapture" permissions in the manifest. No infobar prompt will appear if you include
those.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/camera-capture/manifest.json#L14

If you're writing a normal web app hosted on a web server, than the only way
around the infobar prompt is to run the sight over SSL (https). In that case, users
will only be prompted once. Subsequent uses of your app won't show the prompt if the user
accepts the first time.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem.  My user receives one prompt at the top of the browser (only first time one site) and then a prompt where the video loads.  I just want to know how to tell if the prompt appears and if the user clicks accept or decline.  I tried posting another question with no luck, maybe you can help :) @ebidel

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to launch your browser in command line by using the use-fake-ui-for-media-stream property.

```
start chrome "http://localhost" --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

More informations about Linux and Mac command line instructions here: https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/chrome-always-allow-access-to-webcam-and-microphone-over-http-webrtc/

Comment: Please explicitly state that it's a link to your own blog.